# como pegar um elemento de uma tabela

Tags: mysql, sql

Falando em variáveis que se podem declarar dentro do begin, eu vi que tem Declare e set só que eu não sei quando usar as mesmas. Vi que tem set @x, set x, set x = x+1, set x := x+1; todas elas me confundem e não sei para que servem direito.

Tenho esse código que é para pegar o código do produto que cada cliente mais comprou. Queria que ele pegasse o primeiro cliente de cada código e mostrasse, porque ordenei de forma desc.

Está saindo assim: nomeProduto, codigoProd, cliente, qtdComprada;

`ABAJUR             15    JOSE TAVARES DE OLUVEIRA    2`

`LAPISEIRA 1.2      10    JOSE TAVARES DE OLUVEIRA    1`

`CAIXA DE SOM       16    JOSE TAVARES DE OLUVEIRA    1`

`CANETA VERMELHA     3    MANOEL JOAQUIM PURTUGA      2`

`LAPISEIRA 0.9       9    MANOEL JOAQUIM PURTUGA      1`

Queria mostrar a primeira linha de cada cliente.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS uspProdutoMaisCompradoCliente $$
CREATE PROCEDURE uspProdutoMaisCompradoCliente ()

BEGIN

DECLARE done BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE vNomeProd VARCHAR(250);
DECLARE vNomeCli VARCHAR(250);
DECLARE vQtdComprProd INT(11);
DECLARE contador int;

DECLARE cursor_a CURSOR FOR (
select produto.nome as nomeProd, cliente.nome as cliente,
count(produto.codigo) as qtdComprProd
from cliente
inner join nota_fiscal
on cliente.codigo = nota_fiscal.cod_cliente
inner join item_nota_fiscal
on item_nota_fiscal.numero_nf = nota_fiscal.numero_nf
inner join produto
on produto.codigo = item_nota_fiscal.cod_produto
group by produto.nome , produto.codigo , cliente.nome , cliente.codigo
order by cliente.nome, qtdComprProd desc
);

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET done = TRUE;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tempTabela;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempTabela (
   tNomeProd VARCHAR(250),
  tNomeCli VARCHAR(250),
   tQtdComprProd INT(11)
);

OPEN cursor_a;

REPEAT
FETCH  cursor_a INTO vNomeProd,vNomeCli, vQtdComprProd;

IF NOT done THEN

     INSERT INTO tempTabela VALUES (vNomeProd, vNomeCli, vQtdComprProd);

END IF;

UNTIL done END REPEAT;
close cursor_a;
SELECT * FROM tempTabela;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

**Tabelas:**

```
CREATE TABLE ESTADO (
  ESTADO VARCHAR(02) NOT NULL,
  NOME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ESTADO)
) ;

CREATE TABLE CIDADE (
  CODIGO INTEGER NOT NULL,
  NOME VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  ESTADO VARCHAR(02),
  PRIMARY KEY (CODIGO),
  FOREIGN KEY (ESTADO) REFERENCES ESTADO (ESTADO)
) ;

CREATE TABLE CLIENTE (
  CODIGO INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  NOME VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  RUA VARCHAR(250),
  NUMERO VARCHAR(10),
  COD_CIDADE INTEGER,
  PRIMARY KEY (CODIGO),
  FOREIGN KEY (COD_CIDADE) REFERENCES CIDADE (CODIGO)
);

CREATE TABLE FORNECEDOR (
  CODIGO INTEGER NOT NULL,
  NOME VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  RUA VARCHAR(250),
  NUMERO VARCHAR(10),
  COD_CIDADE INTEGER,
  PRIMARY KEY (CODIGO),
  FOREIGN KEY (COD_CIDADE) REFERENCES CIDADE (CODIGO)
);

CREATE TABLE PRODUTO (
  CODIGO INTEGER NOT NULL,
  NOME VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  PCO_ATUAL_CPA DECIMAL(10,2),
  PCO_ATUAL_VDA DECIMAL(10,2),
  QTD_ESTOQUE INTEGER,
  QTD_EST_MIN INTEGER,
  QTD_EST_MAX INTEGER,
  QTD_PTO_CPA INTEGER,
  IDF_ATIVO_SN VARCHAR(01) DEFAULT 'S',
  COD_FORNECEDOR INTEGER,
  PRIMARY KEY (CODIGO),
  FOREIGN KEY (COD_FORNECEDOR) REFERENCES FORNECEDOR (CODIGO)
) ;

CREATE TABLE NOTA_FISCAL (
  NUMERO_NF INTEGER NOT NULL,
  DTA_VENDA DATE NOT NULL,
  COD_CLIENTE INTEGER,
  VALOR_TOTAL DECIMAL(10,2),
  PRIMARY KEY (NUMERO_NF),
  FOREIGN KEY (COD_CLIENTE) REFERENCES CLIENTE (CODIGO)
) ;

CREATE TABLE ITEM_NOTA_FISCAL (
  NUMERO_NF INTEGER NOT NULL,
  COD_PRODUTO INTEGER NOT NULL,
  QTD_VEDIDA INTEGER,
  PCO_RECEBIDO DECIMAL(10,2),
  PRIMARY KEY (NUMERO_NF, COD_PRODUTO),
  FOREIGN KEY (NUMERO_NF) REFERENCES NOTA_FISCAL (NUMERO_NF),
  FOREIGN KEY (COD_PRODUTO) REFERENCES PRODUTO (CODIGO)
) ;
```

REfiz como o entendi mas da erro:

```
   delimiter $$
        DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS uspProdutoMaisCompradoCliente $$
        CREATE PROCEDURE uspProdutoMaisCompradoCliente ()

        BEGIN

            DECLARE done BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
            DECLARE vNomeProd VARCHAR(250);
            DECLARE vNomeCli VARCHAR(250);
            DECLARE vQtdComprProd INT(11);
            DECLARE contador int;

        DECLARE cursor_a CURSOR FOR (
            select produto.nome as nomeProd, cliente.nome as cliente,
            count(produto.codigo) as qtdComprProd
            from cliente
            inner join nota_fiscal
            on cliente.codigo = nota_fiscal.cod_cliente
            inner join item_nota_fiscal
            on item_nota_fiscal.numero_nf = nota_fiscal.numero_nf
            inner join produto
            on produto.codigo = item_nota_fiscal.cod_produto
            group by produto.nome , produto.codigo , cliente.nome , cliente.codigo
            order by cliente.nome, qtdComprProd desc
        );

        set @itens :=produto.nome as nomeProd, cliente.nome as cliente, count(produto.codigo) as qtdComprProd;


        DECLARE cursor_b CURSOR FOR (
              select @itens from cliente
              inner join nota_fiscal
              on cliente.codigo = nota_fiscal.cod_cliente
              inner join item_nota_fiscal
              on item_nota_fiscal.numero_nf = nota_fiscal.numero_nf
              inner join produto
              on produto.codigo = item_nota_fiscal.cod_produto
              group by produto.nome , produto.codigo , cliente.nome , cliente.codigo
              order by cliente.nome, qtdComprProd desc
        );

        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET done = TRUE;

        DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tempTabela;
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempTabela (
           tNomeProd VARCHAR(250),
          tNomeCli VARCHAR(250),
           tQtdComprProd INT(11)
        );

        OPEN cursor_a;
        OPEN cursor_b;

        REPEAT
        FETCH  cursor_a INTO vNomeProd,vNomeCli, vQtdComprProd;

        IF NOT done THEN

             INSERT INTO tempTabela VALUES (vNomeProd, vNomeCli, vQtdComprProd);

        END IF;

        UNTIL done END REPEAT;
        close cursor_a;
        SELECT * FROM tempTabela;
        END $$
        DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: DECLARE é quando se declara uma variável e seu tipo... (no início de sua criação), SET é quando vc deseja alterar seu comportamento,  e "seta" algum valor para esta variável declarada.

Comment: Refez errado. Itens é uma variável, que contém uma string, se vc não colocar as aspas, vc estará quebrando tudo.

Comment: Na resposta não fiz desta forma.

Answer (score 1):

Usa subquerys,

```
SELECT nomeProduto,
        codigoProd,
        (subquery que busca o cliente que mais comprou) AS cliente,        
        (subquery que busca a quantidade vendida) AS qtdComprada;
FROM PRODUTO ...
```

A subquery é outro select com SELECT FROM WHERE, mas a validação é feita pelas tabelas externas

```
SELECT tabela1.codigo
        (SELECT tabela2.nome FROM tabela2 WHERE tabela2.cliente = tabela1.cliente) as nome_cliente
FROM tabela1
```

Editado: 16/10/2015

```
SELECT CLI.NOME,
        (SELECT PRO.NOME
          FROM PRODUTO PRO
            INNER JOIN ITEM_NOTA_FISCAL INF ON PRO.CODIGO = INF.COD_PRODUTO
            INNER JOIN NOTA_FISCAL NOF ON INF.NUMERO_NF = NOF.NUMERO_NF
          WHERE NOF.COD_CLIENTE = CLI.CODIGO
          GROUP BY PRO.CODIGO, PRO.NOME
          ORDER BY COUNT(PRO.CODIGO) desc
          LIMIT 1) AS NOME,
        (SELECT PRO.CODIGO
          FROM PRODUTO PRO
            INNER JOIN ITEM_NOTA_FISCAL INF ON PRO.CODIGO = INF.COD_PRODUTO
            INNER JOIN NOTA_FISCAL NOF ON INF.NUMERO_NF = NOF.NUMERO_NF
          WHERE NOF.COD_CLIENTE = CLI.CODIGO
          GROUP BY PRO.CODIGO
          ORDER BY COUNT(PRO.CODIGO) desc
          LIMIT 1) AS CODIGO,
        (SELECT COUNT(PRO.CODIGO)
          FROM PRODUTO PRO
            INNER JOIN ITEM_NOTA_FISCAL INF ON PRO.CODIGO = INF.COD_PRODUTO
            INNER JOIN NOTA_FISCAL NOF ON INF.NUMERO_NF = NOF.NUMERO_NF
          WHERE NOF.COD_CLIENTE = CLI.CODIGO
          GROUP BY PRO.CODIGO
          ORDER BY COUNT(PRO.CODIGO) desc
          LIMIT 1) AS QUANT
FROM CLIENTE CLI
```

Olhe o exemplo acima, não tenho o mysql para testar, mas deve trazer como resultado o que solicitou.

O defeito do método é que vai trazer apenas uma linha por produto, portanto se tiver dois clientes com o mesmo numero de compras, apenas virá no resultado, isso pode ser resolvido com uma subquery após o FROM ...

```
SELECT pro.nome
        pro.codigo
        aux.nome
        aux.quant
 FROM PRODUTO pro
   INNER JOIN (select pro_codigo, nome, count(alguma coisa) as quant from relações de tabelas) as aux ON aux.pro_codigo = pro.codigo
...
```

Comment: Não entendi?????

Comment: Editei a resposta.

Comment: o erro que da é esse:
'INF.CODIGO' in 'group statement' 
se eu mudar inf.codigo para inf.cod_produto ou .numero_nf aparece mas mostra todos os resultados  para uma pessoa ou seja mostra tudo das pessoas.não pega só o produto que cad pessoa mais comprou

Comment: E a minha inteção não é de pegar soluções, eu tentei fazer, só que estou com dúvidas e pedindo a ajuda de vcs!!!!
eu coloco esse código em um único cursor, correto?

Comment: A ideia foi dar um exemplo funcional de como usar as subquerys, você terá que entender e ajustar ao seu problema.

Comment: Desculpa se me fiz entender mal, não quis te criticar no último comentário apenas estimular seus esforços.

Boa sorte com seu problema, se precisar questione.

Comment: Sou novo aqui no site, andei lendo sobre perguntas e resposta e a proposta é responder de forma simples e objetiva, então editei minha resposta para se adequar ao objetivo do StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Isso que você se confundiu na verdade é o uso da variável, no caso `set x := x+1` significa uma simples soma de **+1**, ou seja, **x** está recebendo seu valor atual mais **1**.

> **DECLARE** é usado para criar uma variável e definir seu tipo (string, número, booleano, etc).

Não é obrigatório declarar variáveis, mas é boas práticas.

> **SET** é usado para alterar o comportamento de uma variável, cada vez que você faz essa alteração usando: `set @variavel:='Valor'`, significa que você está armazenando um 'Valor' à variável, que por usa vez será usada em outro momento ou quando ela for chamada.

Para mostrar somente a primeira linha, basta retirar os demais nomes no seu select, e criar um novo **produto_nome_nome**, para cada item que desejar mostrar, você pega somente um na lista e cria um novo cursor, no caso estou usando a variável **@nomeProd** para listar os itens da sua consulta:

```
delimiter $$
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS uspProdutoMaisCompradoClienteConsulta $$
    CREATE PROCEDURE uspProdutoMaisCompradoClienteConsulta ()

    BEGIN
      DECLARE @vNomeProd VARCHAR(250);
      DECLARE @vNomeCli VARCHAR(250);
      DECLARE @vQtdComprProd INT(11);

        /* produto */
        DECLARE produto_nome_cursor CURSOR FOR (
            select produto.nome as nomeProd
                  from cliente
                  inner join nota_fiscal
                  on cliente.codigo = nota_fiscal.cod_cliente
                  inner join item_nota_fiscal
                  on item_nota_fiscal.numero_nf = nota_fiscal.numero_nf
                  inner join produto
                  on produto.codigo = item_nota_fiscal.cod_produto
                  group by produto.nome, produto.codigo, cliente.nome, cliente.codigo
        ); 

        /* abre e faz a listagem de produtos */
        OPEN produto_nome_cursor;
        FETCH NEXT FROM produto_nome_cursor INTO @vNomeProd;
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
        BEGIN  
           FETCH NEXT FROM produto_nome_cursor INTO @vNomeProd;
        END;
        CLOSE produto_nome_cursor;
        DEALLOCATE produto_nome_cursor;

        /* cliente */ 
        DECLARE cliente_cursor CURSOR FOR (
            select cliente.nome as cliente
                   from cliente
                   inner join nota_fiscal
                   on cliente.codigo = nota_fiscal.cod_cliente
                   inner join item_nota_fiscal
                   on item_nota_fiscal.numero_nf = nota_fiscal.numero_nf
                   inner join produto
                   on produto.codigo = item_nota_fiscal.cod_produto
                   group by produto.nome, produto.codigo, cliente.nome, cliente.codigo
            ); 

        /* abre e faz a listagem de clientes */
        OPEN cliente_cursor;
        FETCH NEXT FROM cliente_cursor INTO @vNomeCli;
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
        BEGIN  
           FETCH NEXT FROM cliente_cursor INTO @vNomeCli;
        END;
        CLOSE cliente_cursor;
        DEALLOCATE cliente_cursor;

        /* quantidade de compras */ 
        DECLARE qtde_cursor CURSOR FOR (
            select count(produto.codigo) as qtdComprProd
                   from cliente
                   inner join nota_fiscal
                   on cliente.codigo = nota_fiscal.cod_cliente
                   inner join item_nota_fiscal
                   on item_nota_fiscal.numero_nf = nota_fiscal.numero_nf
                   inner join produto
                   on produto.codigo = item_nota_fiscal.cod_produto
                   group by produto.nome, produto.codigo, cliente.nome, cliente.codigo
            ); 

        /* abre e faz a listagem de qtdes */
        OPEN qtde_cursor;
        FETCH NEXT FROM qtde_cursor INTO @vNomeCli;
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
        BEGIN  
           FETCH NEXT FROM qtde_cursor INTO @vNomeCli;
        END;
        CLOSE qtde_cursor;
        DEALLOCATE qtde_cursor;

         /* todos os dados do cliente */ 
        DECLARE dados_cliente_cursor CURSOR FOR (
            select produto.nome as nomeProd,
                   cliente.nome as cliente,
                   count(produto.codigo) as qtdComprProd
                   from cliente
                   inner join nota_fiscal
                   on cliente.codigo = nota_fiscal.cod_cliente
                   inner join item_nota_fiscal
                   on item_nota_fiscal.numero_nf = nota_fiscal.numero_nf
                   inner join produto
                   on produto.codigo = item_nota_fiscal.cod_produto
                   group by produto.nome, produto.codigo, cliente.nome, cliente.codigo
            ); 

        /* abre e faz a listagem de qtdes */
        OPEN dados_cliente_cursor;
        FETCH NEXT FROM dados_cliente_cursor INTO @vNomeCli;
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
        BEGIN  
           FETCH NEXT FROM dados_cliente_cursor INTO @vNomeCli;
        END;
        CLOSE dados_cliente_cursor;
        DEALLOCATE dados_cliente_cursor;
    END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Deixa ver se eu entendi. Eu posso por exemplo declarar carro:
``DECLARE carro int``
depois eu poderia usar de qual forma?:
``set carro = 3``
``set @carro = 3``
``set carro := 3``
``set @carro := 3``
.....
e essas linhas dão erro:
``set @itens :="produto.nome as nomeProd";``

Comment: DECLARE carro int(11); set @carro:=3;

Comment: Acredito que seja só declarar a variável itens: `DECLARE itens VARCHAR(255);` Você tem que fazer como uma string, usando aspas, não pode fazer: `set @itens :=produto.nome as nomeProd, cliente.nome as cliente, count(produto.codigo) as qtdComprProd;`

Comment: Veja se isso te ajuda:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/static.htm#BABHEBAI

Comment: agora entendi o uso das variáveis. muito obrigada! Mas quando coloco o código que fizeste na procedure da erro. o que pode ser?

Comment: Eu editei, o nome do cursor estava errado. veja se está funcionando.

Comment: Sempre publique o erro, para que possamos analisar. Literalmente não podemos prever nenhum comportamento associado à erro sem que haja uma saída da exceção na tela.

Comment: mas eu devo jogar esse código direto na procedure? preciso colocar entre BEGIN e end?
`` DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS uspProdutoMaisCompradoCliente $$
CREATE PROCEDURE uspProdutoMaisCompradoCliente ()

BEGIN``

Comment: Criei como uma nova procedure, para vc.

Comment: A partir do BEGIN as variáveis sao marcadas com erro. Dessa vez fiz eu coloquei certo, mas o erro é apontado na primeira variável depois do begin